# How to open Windows Terminal with 4 panes?

Tags: windows-terminal

I want to open 4 equal panes in Windows Terminal using `wt.exe` from command line. This is the intended result:

[image]

I have attempted using `split-pane`, but without a `focus-pane` command, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do so in any other way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can now start WT using wt.exe from the command line like this (I'm using Windows Terminal Preview version, I'm not sure if you need the Preview version for this or not):

```
wt split-pane -V; move-focus left; split-pane -H; move-focus right; split-pane -H
```

Alternatively, you can use the new [startupActions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup#startup-actions-preview) setting for which you currently definitely need Windows Terminal Preview version.

I just answered myself in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66017010/413785) about this. You can modify your Windows Terminal `settings.json` file by adding the following line to the root of your setting:

```
  "startupActions": "split-pane -V; move-focus left; split-pane -H; move-focus right; split-pane -H"
```

This means however that this will now be your default (even when you start WT from Start or from the taskbar, not only through the command line.

Comment: Please do not miss to read "Windows Terminal Preview" if you are trying "move-focus"

Comment: @EMalik Now that the "normal" version (as in, "not preview") [has reached 1.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-7-release/), the preview version is no longer needed.

Comment: 4x4 panes: `wt sp -V; mf left; sp -H; mf up; sp -V; sp -H; mf left; sp -H; mf down; sp -V; sp -H; mf left; sp -H; mf right; mf right; sp -H; mf up;  sp -V; sp -H; mf left; sp -H; mf down;  sp -V; sp -H; mf left; sp -H`

Comment: 3x2 panes: `"startupActions": "split-pane -s .66 -V; split-pane -s .5 -V; split-pane -H; move-focus left; split-pane -H; move-focus left; split-pane -H; move-focus up",`. This way the focus is in the top left pane on startup.

Answer (score 8):

**Update on 09/06/2021**

We can finally achieve it through command line arguments. Here is a working example:

```bash
wt -M -d "./dir-a"; ^
split-pane -V -d "./dir-b"; ^
move-focus left; ^
split-pane -H -d "./dir-c"; ^
move-focus right; ^
split-pane -H -d "./dir-d"
```

**Old Answer**

I was able to get it working programatically using JScript. Not as beautiful as using `wt.exe` arguments, but it is the best we can do from a bat file nowadays.

```js
@if (@X) == (@Y) @end /*
@cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%*"
@exit /b %errorlevel%
*/

// run windows terminal
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("wt.exe");
WScript.Sleep(500);

// ALT+SHIFT+=
shell.SendKeys("%+=");
WScript.Sleep(500);

// ALT+SHIFT+-
shell.SendKeys("%+-");
WScript.Sleep(500);

// focus left pane
shell.SendKeys("%{LEFT}");

// ALT+SHIFT+-
WScript.Sleep(500);
shell.SendKeys("%+-");
```

Comment: Thi sis pretty amazing, thank you!

Looks like "%{LEFT}" is not working here, what exactly is that key,  is it just the left keyboard key?

Comment: It is the left keyboard key with alt pressed

Comment: this answer is outdated, check out the top voted answer

Comment: It would be fairer to link to the correct answer rather than adding it into an earlier post.

Answer (score 5):

I am able to do that with this single command from windows terminal (wt) :

```
wt -p "Command Prompt" `; sp -V -p "openSUSE-Leap-15-1" `; sp -H -p "Windows PowerShell"; [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); Start-Sleep -s 2; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{LEFT}"); Start-Sleep -s 2; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%+{5}")
```

it starts from top left and go as a clockwise, then stop at bottom left,
in my windows terminal the sequences are : cmd prompt, opensuse, windows powershell, and kali linux,

it will opens 4 panes equally in windows terminal.

[image]

Run it on windows terminal (wt) with power shell.

Add these 2 examples in your windows terminal settings.json

```
{ "command": { "action": "splitPane", "split": "horizontal", "index": 4 }, "keys": "alt+shift+5" }

"backgroundImage": "%USERPROFILE%/Downloads/win_terminal_bg_img/kali_linux.jpg",
"backgroundImageOpacity": 0.3
```

where index 4 and  alt shift 5 (("%+{5}")) refer to kali-linux in my windows terminal (wt) menu,
and the image is for its background,

add those 2 examples sequentially and customize it with your wt menu.

Here are the tutorials :

https://www.howtogeek.com/673729/heres-why-the-new-windows-10-terminal-is-amazing/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#move-pane-focus
https://pureinfotech.com/set-image-background-windows-terminal/

Good Luck.

Comment: Make sure you are invoking wt from command prompt. I was doing it from another windows terminal and it was not working

Answer (score -1):

I'd like this, but I don't think it is possible currently.

The best I can manage is 3 panes, 1x Half and 2x Quarters. As you say, another split will always give 1x Half, 1x Quarter, 2x Eighths.

I tried with profiles to load another wt and split the first pane, but its always a new window/process.

**Update:**
Its possible to [moveFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings#move-pane-focus) between panes with a keyboard shortcut, so it could be possible to write a PowerShell script that does this.

Comment: I got it working from a bat file if you are interested

Comment: Excellent work, I tried with a Powershell script embedded in a profile in Settings.json, but I think that was a mistake. The parameters are difficult to pass without encountering parse errors.

Comment: @VitorSubs I'm curious, please share.

Comment: @JohnHomer check the accepted answer. It sends keyboard commands to the process. Unfortunately there is no better of doing it yet.